# Docusign template text not updating through api

Tags: docusignapi

Old Docusign template text appears through api but new text appears when sent directly from docusign. Branding updates to template updated through api so not sure why text would not update? Docusign customer service referred me to here

Answer (score 0):

by "template text" I wonder if you mean the subject/blurb that is sent to the signers. this can be either from the original template, or can be override during the creation of the envelope, depending on how you make your API calls. Please share how you do that so we can further assist you.